# SharePoint - MultiChoice doesn't show up in Content Types returned by REST interface

Tags: sharepoint-2010, multichoiceitems

I've added a multichoice column to a content type, and when I call listdata.svc and look inside of the content types and find the content type I've added this column too, the multichoice column isn't there. When I change the column to a dropdown it appears in the content type that's returned in the listdata.svc results.

Is there any reason why I can't get a multichoice column to show up?

Answer (score 0):

By default SharePoint REST service does not return multi-value lookup fields, but you could use the `$expand` operator to make a projection in order to return those values.

The following REST query demonstrates how to return multi-value lookup fields:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks(<ItemId>)?$select=TaskName,TaskCategories&$expand=TaskCategories
```

where `TaskCategories` is the name of multi-choice column.